# Magento Search is unable to search fulltext

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

I have products with names like **Elite: 16-27** and SKU like **ELW-16-27**

I am trying to use **full text** search functionality so that a user should get exact match for the product.

if he/she searches with **Elite: 16-27** but I am not getting it as expected rather.It is giving all the results with **Elite:** and if I am searching with **16-27**.

it is showing no result.

Can anyone please help me here?

Answer (score -1):

You should try this

```
1. Check product Quantity and Stock and that product is assigned to a category
2. Clear Cache
3. Run Re-Indexing.
```

Comment: This is not the case